# How to implement a spectrum kernel function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, n-gram

A spectrum kernel function operates on strings by counting the same n-grams in between two strings. For example, 'tool' has three 2-grams ('to', 'oo', and 'ol'), and the similarity between 'tool' and 'fool' is 2. ('oo' and 'ol' in common).

How can I write a MATLAB function that could calculate this metric?

Comment: It sounds to me like you are interested in creating a Kernel function for some other purpose, say, for a support vector machine classifier. For that, the hamming distance alone does not take full advantage of the information available. Look to the source links here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_kernel Good luck! I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step would be to create a function that can generate an n-gram for a given string. One way to do this in a vectorized fashion is with some clever indexing.

```
function [subStrings, counts] = n_gram(fullString, N)
  if (N == 1)
    [subStrings, ~, index] = unique(cellstr(fullString.'));  %.'# Simple case
  else
    nString = numel(fullString);
    index = hankel(1:(nString-N+1), (nString-N+1):nString);
    [subStrings, ~, index] = unique(cellstr(fullString(index)));
  end
  counts = accumarray(index, 1);
end
```

This uses the function [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) to first create a matrix of indices that will select each set of unique N-length substrings from the given string. Indexing the given string with this index matrix will create a character array with one N-length substring per row. The function [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html) then places each row of the character array into a cell of a cell array. The function [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) then removes repeated substrings, and the function [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html) is used to count the occurrences of each unique substring (if they are needed for any reason).

With the above function you can then easily count the number of n-grams shared between two strings using the [INTERSECT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/intersect.html) function:

```
subStrings1 = n_gram('tool',2);
subStrings2 = n_gram('fool',2);
sharedStrings = intersect(subStrings1,subStrings2);
nShared = numel(sharedStrings);
```

Comment: You should add
  subStrings = intersect(subStrings, subStrings);
to the function n_gram to avoid repetition.  For instance, n_gram('hubbub', 2) would have a repeated 'ub' member in the original formulation.

Comment: @mtrw: Good point, but the function UNIQUE would work better. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Oof.  Yeah, UNIQUE would be quite a bit more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called the Hamming distance, you can get a better description of it if you do `doc pdist`.

```
A=['Marcin'; 'Martin'; 'Marsha']  %data

squareform(pdist(A, 'hamming'))  returns

         0    0.1667    0.5000

    0.1667         0    0.5000

    0.5000    0.5000         0
```

This form shows you how many letters are different.  Difference between 'Marcin' and 'Martin' is 1 out of 6 letters, so you get 1/6=0.1667  'Marcin' vs 'Marsha' has 3 of 6, so 3/6=0.5
If you want the actual number of letters that are different, just multiply the whole matrix by length(A).

Comment: This doesn't quite sound like what the question describes.